# Mail client with schema.org/ViewAction support

Tags: email-client

Gmail [supports](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/) Schema.org’s [`ViewAction`](http://schema.org/ViewAction), which means I can get buttons directly in the list view of my email folder, e.g., to view an issue or respond to a pull request.

Are there other mail clients that support `ViewAction`?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with you research?

Comment: no, I did not get any further.